# Gradle Kotlin DSL: Extract contents from dependency

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How do I convert the following snippet (based on the one by [Peter Niederwieser](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/right-way-to-copy-contents-from-dependency-archives/7449/13)) to Kotlin?

```
configurations {
    assets
}
dependencies {
    assets 'somegroup:someArtifact:someVersion'
}
task extractApi(type: Sync) {
    dependsOn configurations.assets

    from { // use of closure defers evaluation until execution time
        configurations.assets.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
    into "$buildDir/assets/"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't experience with the Kotlin DSL, but apparently the `extractApi` task could be re-written as

```
val assets by configurations.creating

dependencies {
    assets("somegroup", "someArtifact", "someVersion")
}

tasks {
    val extractApi by creating(Sync::class) {
        dependsOn(assets)

        from(assets.map {
            zipTree(it)
        })

        into("$buildDir/api/")
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. It gives me the following error: `Line 145:         from() {
                           ^ Passing value as a vararg is only allowed inside a parenthesized argument list`

Comment: @MichelKrämer And without "()"?

Comment: I suppose you mean /with/ parentheses because the error message clearly indicates that parentheses are needed. If I leave them off, I get the same error message. If I add them around the closure I get: `Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: () -> kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Any!>`

Comment: @MichelKrämer okay. Well I'll just create a new project using Kotlin DSL. Let's see

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't do anything. What does `path needed!` mean?

Comment: @MichelKrämer well apparently an argument to the "from" method must be always provided. You cannot leave it out. I had a look at the sources and it seems so

Comment: Yes, but did you also test the build script? AFAICT it does not copy anything.

Comment: @MichelKrämer done. Tested and working, more or less. May need some adjustements. But seems the right solution to me

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remember to include the "dependsOn"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works indeed. I was wondering about the `isCanBeResolved`. I replaced it with `dependsOn` and it still works. I think `dependsOn` is the cleaner solution. If you update your answer, I'd more than happy to accept it.

Comment: @MichelKrämer Thank you. Before editing the answer I'd like to understand better how you got it working. I had to add it, to avoid the error "Resolving configuration 'apiElements' directly is not allowed"

Comment: Ah, I see. My configuration is called `assets`. I had to create it with `val assets by configurations.creating`. After that I did not need the `isCanBeResolved` anymore. By the way, `isCanBeResolved` is deprecated and will be removed in Gradle 6.

Comment: I'll update the question so that it also uses `assets` instead of `api`

Comment: @MichelKrämer ahhh so it was a custom configuration, not the included "api" one (which is a recent addition to Gradle)

Comment: @MichelKrämer done! Btw, thank you, I had to study a bit of the Kotlin DSL and it was fun